# Auto Switching USB ports when in use

Tags: pcb-design, usb

[image]I'm looking at adding multiple USB C ports to a PCB design that all perform the same function (power and data in device most). How can I switch to a port automatically when in use and disable the other ports that are left to prevent the use of more than one port simultaneously? A controller perhaps? thanks

Comment: What USB speed are you running at? Keep in mind that this sort of device would not be USB compliant.

Comment: "slave" isn't an official USB term. Do you mean "device" (as opposed to "host')? If so, your device will consume power (and not provide it). Is that correct?

Comment: This will not be simple; there are mux chips and there are MCU's with multiple interfaces, but **why do you want to do this?**  You're going to need to provide more comprehensive information to get an answer, also the number of ports needed.

Comment: Please provide more details about what, specifically, you are trying to accomplish with this.  There may be much better approaches.

Comment: The need for multiple USB ports is so the product can be orientated in portrait or landscape, there could be ways around using multiple ports, but I just wanted to know if it was possible and if so what would it require, two ports would probably be ideal.

Comment: @Jon USB 2.0, can you give me some more info on why this would not be compliant? thanks

Comment: @ChrisStratton The USB ports are being used to provide power and data to an ATSAM3X8E and link with a PC on the other end

Comment: That's really not enough information, you should edit the question with a block diagram of the entire system.   If (best guess) you are trying to connect the MCU as a peripheral to a PC via one of two ports, you could use a USB mux controlled via software queued via the USB VBUS lines (which would probably have diode voting for power) or you could use instead an MCU with dual USB interfaces (ST for example has several comparable parts with that, Atmel/Microchip may as well).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your help, sorry for the lack of info, first time posting here. Your guess is correct, for the second point are you suggesting I replace the current ATSAM MCU with and MCU with dual USB Interfaces or add a separate one to handle this? Also, could you give me an example of a viable MUX or MCU for both examples, please? Something like this https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC32MK1024GPE100 maybe? Thank you